# Using @DeleteMapping will cause a Request method 'POST' not supported error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I've created a RESTful HTMLController, but delete not work.

HTMLController have a method:

```
@DeleteMapping("{id}")
fun destory(@PathVariable id: Long): String {
    deleteFooService.execute(id)
    return "redirect:/foos"
}
```

thymeleaf have the form:

```
<form th:action="@{/foos/{id}(id=*{id})}" th:method="delete">
  <input class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
```

When I press the delete button, the following error will occur:

```
2020-06-03 22:19:03.437  WARN 17163 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Incidentally, curl has been successful:

```
~(:|✔) % curl -v -X DELETE "http://localhost:8080/foos/1"   
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> DELETE /foos/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Location: http://localhost:8080/foos
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 13:05:54 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

And I confirmed the thymeleaf code is converted to the following HTML code:

```
<form action="/foos/1" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
  <input class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the form with `_method` **not works by default** after Spring Boot 2.2.

HTML5 still doesn't allow you to use the `PUT` and `DELETE` HTTP methods. So one way to do this is to use the hidden parameters. This was turned off by default.

To make it effective, add the following code to `application.properties`.

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled: true
```

See:

[Spring Boot 2.2 Release Notes · spring-projects/spring-boot Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#httphiddenmethodfilter-disabled-by-default)

> HttpHiddenMethodFilter disabled by default
>   The filter that handles the _method request parameter is now disabled by default as it causes early consumption of a request body if the body may contain parameters. This can be restored by setting either spring.webflux.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled or spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while using Spring boot 2.4.

In my case, I had same error message when I used '@deleteMapping'.

I changed it to

`@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})`

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled: true
```

adding this in my application.properties file worked

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled: true
```

adding this in my application.properties file worked